# Python Table to one entry per column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to generate a data set for 300 months that shows how a solar panel degrades. It starts at 100% in months 1-12. In the 13-24th month it produces at 99.5% of it's original amount. In month 25-36 it produces at 99.5%^2 of it's ability in the first 12 months. How do I create 300 columns which account for this?

```
Python
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    theo = np.outer(np.ones(12), np.hstack([1, np.cumprod(np.ones(24) * .995)]))
    np.reshape(theo, [1, -1], order='F')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(theo).T
    df2.index += 1
    df2.index
    stacked_df=df2.stack()
```

Leads to a data set with 300 rows (with the leading rows corresponding to years 1-25). 
I.e. row 2-13 is year 1, with 100%
     row 14-25 is year 2 with 99.5%
     row 25-37 is year 3 with 99.0025%
     ...
     row 290-301 is year 25 with 88.6654%

[Attached output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zMa1.jpg)

My desired output is 300 columns.

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zMa1.jpg)

[Output goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vlg0.jpg)

One of the questions asked why I want to 300 columns. I need to eventually store this in a database.

Comment: why do you need 300 columns? Show us what you want the table to look like. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Show us a snippet of your data. You can mock up example data with smaller dimensions, don't show us 300 columns. Also, you seem to want to aggregate 300 months into 12-month rows, there would be 300/12 = 25 such bins, not 300 of them. When you say *"How do I create 300 columns which account for this?"* it sounds like you want to go in reverse i.e. unpack the bins, but how are you going to get monthly-level data, you're only going to have annual averages? I don't see how you can. Anyway, show us what code you've tried.

Comment: I do not want to aggregate the data. I realize it currently will be redundant for months 1-12, 13-24, 25-36, etc. Once I get this first part completed, I will perform a vector multiplication to account for difference expected in each month.